# After "Oops! Something bad happened" one should be able to try again

Tags: feature-request, 500-server-error

Currently I have to manually remove the `/error?aspxerrorpath=` part from the address to try again. And right now a lot of Oopses happen!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Workin on ur problemz" should contain a link for retrying the request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68280/workin-on-ur-problemz-should-contain-a-link-for-retrying-the-request)

Comment: @DonaldDuck Hey, I dupe-linked that one the other way around seven years ago! 

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Good call on that; this (looks like it) has a better answer and higher scores all around, not to mention being a few months older.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just hit reload on the oops page.

I know, I know, it's not obvious, but it works.

Comment: I am *relatively* certain I did that and received the Oops again while removing the error part from the URL helped. But that does of course prove nothing since the error might just have needed the time I used for editing to fix up... But next time I'll try more often

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to downvote, but I just confirmed that this is not the case.  Example:

<http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/10081973/jsessionid-not-changing-after-user-logs-out-is-this-a-security-issue>

Comment: Also confirmed a reload will not work to redirect away from the error page - I have to remove the "/error?aspxerrorpath=" part in order to get back to the question.