# When "something bad" happens, SO should return a 500, not redirect to an error page

Tags: bug, 500-server-error, redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Offline for maintenance” should not lose the link I tried to open](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66537/offline-for-maintenance-should-not-lose-the-link-i-tried-to-open)

Really, this drives me insane. Every time there's an error of some sort,  I get redirected from stackoverflow.com/foo to stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/foo . The page is served with a 500 status code, but there's two issues here:

1. The page that actually has the error returns a 301/302, which is wrong - the resource hasn't moved.
2. It ensures that no matter how many times I refresh the page, I always get the error page, because I've been redirected. To try again, I have to edit the URL - potentially, over and over.

I really thought terrible practices like this were restricted to sites far more poorly written than SO.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/after-oops-something-bad-happened-one-should-be-able-to-try-again says you can just reload your page without removing the error path.

Comment: @systempuntoout After the latest temporary outage, I can verify that this is not true.

Comment: I can also confirm this is still happening.  I just got redirected to /error (presumably related to the server move), and only after a while of periodically refreshing did I notice that it *redirected* me rather than showing an error message in the standard way, and I had to manually edit the URL to get back to where I was.  Jeff's answer of #57412's "fix" (adding a link to the error page) is very incorrect.  The correct fix is as you said: temporary error messages like these should not cause a permanent redirect.  This is HTTP 101.

Comment: @glenn it's part of the ASP.NET pipeline -- file it against Microsoft, not us.

Comment: The same goes for "currently offline". That also shouldn't redirect but stay at the correct URL and just return an error page. I was just now sitting there and kept reloading `app_offline.htm`, waiting for SO to come back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is already covered by this page (offline).

["Offline for maintenance" should not lose the link I tried to open](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66537/offline-for-maintenance-should-not-lose-the-link-i-tried-to-open/66631#66631)

Perhaps we could modify the actual error page to do the same?

Realize too that what you're complaining about is a core part of the ASP.NET pipeline, not something we wrote.

Also, how often are you getting errors (outside of catastrophic acts of God like the datacenter shutting off all power) that this is a real, practical problem?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to amend the page as you describe. It's still a broken way to do things, from a semantic POV - the actual page having the error should be the one returning the 500. I don't see errors _that_ frequently, but every time I do, it reduces my sanity meter just a little bit that it's as redirect. Perhaps I'm weird.