# "Workin on ur problemz" should contain a link for retrying the request

Tags: feature-request, 500-server-error

Once in a while after I try to open a page I see ["Something bad happened" page with a lolcat](https://stackoverflow.com/error). Usually this page only shows up once in a while and doesn't account for a permanent problem. So it would be nice to be able to try to open the original page again.

The URL for that page sort of contains the original URL - it looks like this

```
https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/OriginalSubPathITriedToOpen
```

so I can technically edit it in the "URL" field in my browser and try to reopen the page, but this is not very convenient (but definitely [better than it was with "Offline for maintenance"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66537/132564)).

Could you please provide a "you can retry this request" link the same way as [on "Offline for maintenance"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66537/offline-for-maintenance-should-not-lose-the-link-i-tried-to-open/66631#66631) page?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if problem is due to DDoS or other overload on servers, link to try again would be a good way to prevent servers from going back to normal work. If anything, link like that should appear by JavaScript not sooner than after, let's say, 2 minutes. Trying again to soon should be discouraged.