# Include original link on error page

Tags: feature-request, bug, hyperlinks, error-message, 500-server-error

Recently I've tried to open my profile, but there was a problem with a server. So I've been redirected to: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/15479/suvitruf-says-reinstate-monica.

> [image: 500 error message]

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/after-oops-something-bad-happened-one-should-be-able-to-try-again), reloading the page should have redirected me to the profile page when it's up again, but that's not the case anymore, and I have to manually browse to the page.

Can you please either fix this bug, or instead include the original link which user has tried to open, to this error message so the user can retry easily?

Comment: No need to have a link, if you reload the server itself will redirect to the actual page. At least that's how it used to be, so if it's not, it should be reported as a bug. :)

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard no, it will not redirect. That's the problem.

Comment: So bug report is due, linking to what I chose as dupe target here to "prove" it used to work this way.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard ok. I've updated the question.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard thanks for editing (:

Comment: Edited it even further to be both a bug report and a feature request. Cheers! :)

Comment: I had the same issue recently. I though this was normal behavior and, thus, didn't reported it. So, thanks for this post.